# Error in using the java Math class in an array

Tags: java

I'm trying to print the largest number of 2 numbers using java Math but I keep getting an error. I'm new to Java and I would really appreciate the help.

Code:

```
public class Math {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Math.max(5, 10));  
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Math.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.println(Math.max(5, 10));
                           ^
  symbol:   method max(int,int)
  location: class Math
1 error
```

Comment: You overwrite system Math class with your same named class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you called your class `Math` as well. The compiler wants to find the method `max` in your own class.

To fix that, give your class another name.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Math {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(java.lang.Math.max(5, 10));  
  }
}
```

or you can import the class `import java.lang.Math;`

Answer (score 1):

Replace `Math` with `java.lang.Math` and this would work.

```
class Math {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(java.lang.Math.max(5, 10));
    }
}
```